# Amount of 2 amperage

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-current

I have 2 equation describing the alternating amperage $I_1$ and $I_2$. I need to get amount of these amperages.

My equations:
$$I_1=10\sin(\omega t+30)$$
$$I_2=20\sin(\omega t-50)$$

How can i make it? I forgot.

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't post your homework, if that's what this is.  Otherwise, it's unclear to me what you're asking.

Comment: @shk: do you need to add i1 and i2 and reduce to the shortest form?

Comment: Better always use "current" instead of "amperage", especially on a physics site.

Comment: I am not sure what you are really asking here. Do you just want the R.M.S. current?

Comment: What's wrong with "amperage"?  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/amperage

Comment: @endolith, Because "amperage" has the stereotype clinging to it that it's only used by people who don't know what current or amperes are. Please note I'm not saying that stereotype is necessarily true.

Comment: @ptomato: Hmm, I just view them as synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume that you ask R.M.S. current and will answer that. If you want some other form of answer just clarify the question a bit more and I'll adjust the answer.

To calculate the RMS(Root-Mean-Square) value of a current, you do the following calculation:

$\sqrt{\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T i(t) dt }$

where T is the period of the signal and t is the variable of integration.

Comment: Oh let me note that you can apply superposition to add both RMS values up, provided that your circuitry is linear.